# Using Linux iptables to implement a stateless, packet filtering firewall

Tags: firewalls, iptables

When I began my career in network security, almost a decade back, the industry standard was stateful firewalls that even had the ability to inspect some application layer protocols. I had only heard that a packet filtering firewall was the previous generation of firewalls. I never got to work with and understand how a strict packet filtering, stateless firewall works. Now, I want to understand it better. I had an intern ask me this and I want to show  him the difference between the 2 firewalls. I believe iptables can be used to set up a stateless packet filtering firewall. The thing is I am not sure how a stateless firewall would track incoming responses that originate from the behind the firewall. I tried my best to find some resources online on how to implement such a firewall. Any pointers to some article would be very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

For a stateless firewall, you can either accept or drop a packet based on its protocol, port number and origin ip address. For example, the rule below accepts all TCP packets from the 192.168.1.x subnet that are bound for port 80.

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -s 192.168.1.0/24 -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

For output, the rules look similar. Therefore, outgoing(egress) packets are only accepted if there is a matching rule. The rule below allows only outgoing packets on port 80.

```
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

For a stateful firewall, you have the ability to monitor state. For example, the rule below only accepts packets to port 80 if it is initiating a new connection or is associated with an existing connection. The tracking is done by a kernel module "ip_conntrack". It keeps a table of all active connections.

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: What about rule for the return traffic for egress packets?

Comment: The first rule. Since it is stateless, it cannot differentiate return traffic from new traffic so it can only decide based on protocol, port number and origin ip address.

Comment: Suppose I go out to `www.google.com` from the LAN. This would mean something like `192.168.1.100:5400 -> www.google.com:80`. Now the return traffic would be `www.google.com:80 -> 192.168.1.100:5400`. How did a stateless firewall handle this sort of return traffic? What rules did they have in place to tackle such traffic?

Comment: You would have to manually open port 513 to 65535 for it to happen. Have a look at http://serverfault.com/questions/253508/iptables-blocking-ssh-even-after-its-been-implicitly-enabled. The first 2 answers use the ip_conntrack module to provide stateful capability. The last uses only stateless features.

Comment: @user1720897 The stateless firewall inspect every packet and work with a set of rules. To allow access to google, it will need to allow outgoint SYN packet to port 80, to permit return traaffic, the incoming SYN-ACK need to be allowed. And ACK bidirectional traffic to the TCP connection to work. Blocking incoming SYN packet will block incoming TCP connections.